# Entityframework Core Migrations

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a .net core 2 project, along with Entity framework Core.

I have an existing database, and I've mapped them out to database entities in code.

The problem is that when I add a migration, expectedly it picks up my entity as a new table, however it is an existing table. The table shares the same name.

I suppose, I could just remove the contents of the Up method of the migration, but I want to know if there is a proper way instead of a workaround.

So, what I am asking is how can I tell entity framework core that this table is already existing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF 6 had an `-IgnoreChanges` option that would just take a snapshot with no Up() code, but that feature is not in EF Core (yet). See [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/4237).

If you comment out the Up() code as you have suggested that will indeed capture a snapshot of your existing objects and subsequent migrations will be incremental.